# How do I link to objects movement with each other?

Tags: animation, node-editor, constraints, geometry, drivers

I want to create like a animation but not a animation, so what I want is whenever I rotate cube number 1 I want number 2 to go in a vertical movement, so when I rotate cube 1 by 360 degree cube 2 should go to a point in a vertical world and come back by the time the cube 1 has done the 360 turn.

Is there any way to solve this? I was thinking about motion linking but don't know how it works. Any help? (:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! Have you tried looking into [Drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/usage.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can use a driver to do that.

[image]

1- Select Cube2, right click on its Z coordinate and add a driver.

Open the driver editor window, and

2- Use Cube1 and its Z rotation as source. Name it zAngle

3- Define the formula you want. For instance, abs(sin(zAngle)) will ping pong between 0 and 1 and multiply it with some factor (for instance 10).

Comment: thanks very much man solved my problem

Comment: hi  me again  there is a slight problem well i am trying to make a engine animation by using this and i want to animate the pistons and as you know piston move in a V shape inwhich x and y axis are moved so how to i rework it to behave i want it to do ?

Comment: You can add another driver for another axis.